# Why the order to protect Leonard?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-umbrella-academy

While Five from *The Umbrella Academy* is in the past he intercepts a message to protect Leonard.  However, later on Vanya ends up killing Leonard, but that didn't stop the apocalypse from happening.

So, what was the intent of sending the message to protect Leonard if his death lead straight to the apocalypse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely because Leonard had to be alive long enough to instigate Vanya's wrath.  The series of events that made Vanya literally explode was:

1. Vanya meets Leonard
2. Vanya falls in love with Leonard
3. Leonard gains Vanya's trust
4. Allison attempts to split Vanya and Leonard.
5. Vanya slits Allison's throat.
6. Leonard and Vanya run away and he tries to convince her to get revenge on her family.
7. Vanya gets enraged and murders Leonard.
8. Vanya goes to the concert and the apocalypse begins.

So Leonard was vital to Vanya's descent in to madness. The last four steps in particular happened in the span of a few hours which is a lot for someone to handle. If he was murdered by someone else at an earlier point, then Vanya could have potentially been talked back down. Since she was the one that killed him, and since she was the one that felt betrayed by everyone in her life, she was willing to destroy everything.

Comment: Though it's important to note, that we arn't exactly sure what Vanya's intent was to actually destroy the earth...as her only coping mechanism was to descend into music...this also happened to be the energy source of her power....the apocalypse as it happened was a side effect of Allison shooting a gun off and 'deafening' Vanya.... causing he to release the energy as a beam hitting the moon....But this also depends if the Apocalypse was always supposed to be from the moon, or Vanya releasing her energy within the Timeline.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the FIRSt apocalypse that has happened, Leonard was still alive: we know that because of Number Five, who found Leonard's fake eye in the rubble.
So we can guess that they wanted to repeat it again, which required Leonard to live up to the end of the world - he must have been somehow the catalyst for the apocalypse, while in the second one, his role was more limited.